# Invisible reCAPTCHA gives "Please check your internet connection and reload" error

Tags: google-chrome, recaptcha, invisible, invisible-recaptcha

I have a "Invisible reCAPTCHA" issue.

I have implemented an Invisible reCAPTCHA in my web application and After implemented this functionality works successfully around 10 to 15 days but right now I am getting bellow error.

Errors:

> Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.
>
> Alternatively if you think you are getting this page in error, please check your internet connection and reload.

Why is this happening?

[image]

My browsers are updated. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now, resolved the invisible reCAPTCHA issue following below steps!

**Solutions** - Previously I am using the bundling concepts to render the Google invisible reCAPTCHA APIs scripts i.e.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/recaptcha", "//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js").Include("~/Scripts/recaptcha-api.js"));
```

So, the above invisible reCAPTCHA API scripts is not rendering with secure https port (https: //www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'). It’s simply render non secure port (http: //www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'). So Google invisible reCAPTCHA not processing your request successfully!

Now, I am using the below line of code to rendering reCAPTCHA API scripts i.e.

```
@Scripts.Render("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js")
```

I hope you are enjoying with this post! Please share with you friends. Thank you so much!

Comment: i have same problem, but i dont know how to write this line in html or php

Comment: @PrasannaMane this is C#, this is why it looked strange to you. 
For your case, simply include <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script> in the header of your HTML file